# How to pass multiple variables as SUDS data in python?

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, suds

Usually, I use dicts to call soap methods:

```
  SoapData = {'id':'1', 'nya':'meow'}
  Check ('SoapMethodName', SoapData)
```

It creates something like this:

```
<data:id>1</data:id>

<data:nya>meow</data:nya>
```

That works fine. But sometimes I need something like this in request:

```
<arg1>12<arg1>

<arg2>meow<arg1>
```

That means I can not use dictionaries. So I need a new function, which gets 2 data arguments:

```
  Check2 ('SoapMethodName', id, nya)
```

What if 20 data arguments are needed? How do I pass them? Arrays do not seem to work, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
args = [id, nya]
Check2('SoapMethodName', *args)
```